# memtier benchmark understanding the output

Tags: get, redis, set, benchmarking

Hi I am very new to using memtier benchmarking tool for redis. I have ran basic examples and not able to understand the output. Can someone help me to understand the below output.

```
Command: memtier_benchmark -s 172.25.1.100 -p 6380 -c 50 -t 100 -n 1000 -d 1000000 --ratio=1:1 --pipeline=1 --key-pattern S:S -P redis
```

Output:

```
100       Threads
50        Connections per thread
1000      Requests per thread
Type        Ops/sec     Hits/sec   Misses/sec      Latency       KB/sec
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sets         748.28          ---          ---   6475.61800    730780.68
Gets         748.28         0.00       748.28    208.12400        22.57
Waits          0.00          ---          ---      0.00000          ---
Totals      1496.57         0.00       748.28   3341.87100    730803.25
```

Answer (score 8):

The output you have posted means that

1. You used 100 threads (-t specifies the number of threads used)
2. Each thread used 50 connections to the redis db (-c 50)
3. Each connection sent 1000 requests (-n 1000)
4. You redis server can perform 748.28 SET and GET operations.
5. The size of the requests is specified on the right and shows that
   the SET requests are quite large and have a very high latency (in milli seconds) compared to the GET requests.
6. In total you can run 1496.57 ops/sec against your redis server.

If this doesn't answer your question then be specific with what you couldn't understand.

Comment: Can you explain "Misses/sec?" Why are the number of Misses equal the the number of Gets? Thanks.

Comment: @Colfax That's because a read request was sent for the key which didn't already exist in the database. So it is counted as a miss.

In the given example, the --key-pattern is S:S so the SET and GET are sequential, which means, if there will be a SET for memtier-0 the next GET will be for memtier-1 and then following SET will be for memtier-2 instead of memtier-1.

Hope this is useful.

Comment: The latency provided by memtier_benchmark include network latency too?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following command to know the memtier parameters:

`memtier_benchmark --help`

See more information in Redislabs:

https://redislabs.com/blog/memtier_benchmark-a-high-throughput-benchmarking-tool-for-redis-memcached/